# Finding start and end indices of positive curves in data

Tags: matlab, difference, indices

Consider the following example where `x`  is

```
x = [randi([10 20],1,10) zeros(1,11) randi([10 20],1,10) zeros(1,11) randi([10 20],1,10) zeros(1,12) randi([10 20],1,11) ];
```

which looks something like this in the plot:

[image]

Now what I want to find is the starting and ending index of each positive curve in the graph and store them in a matrix. The code I have written below works fine but it isn't what I will call elegant. Does anyone have a better and more efficient way of doing it?

```
zero_padding = zeros(1,2);
x = [randi([10 20],1,10) zeros(1,11) randi([10 20],1,10) zeros(1,11) randi([10 20],1,10) zeros(1,12) randi([10 20],1,11) ];
x = [x zero_padding]
stp(1) = find(x>0 , 1, 'first')
enp(1) = find(x(stp(1):end)==0 , 1, 'first') - 1
stoffset = enp(1);
i = 2
while(~isempty(find(x(stoffset + 1:end)>0 , 1, 'first')))        
    stp(i) = find(x(stoffset + 1:end)>0 , 1, 'first') + stoffset
    enp(i) = find(x(stp(i) + 1:end) == 0 , 1, 'first') + stp(i) - 1
    stoffset = (enp(i)) + 1;
    i = i + 1;    
end
```

and the output is:

```
>> stp =

     1    22    43    65


>> enp =

    10    31    52    75
```

which is correct.

*NOTE:* I have already tried using:

```
startindex = (find(diff(x)>0)) + 1
endindex = (find(diff(x)<0))
```

which would work just fine if the positive curves were just perfect squares but as you can see in the plots, it has many dips. So it's difficult to use it as `diff` will also give +1 or -1 at those dips.

Comment: look at `diff(data > 0)`, you should be able to work if out from there (hint returns `1` when your 'positive curves' start and `-1` where they end)

Comment: @Dan I have already tried that approach the problem arises when there are many dips in the positives curves as you youcan see in the x plot`diff(data > 0)` will also give us indices of those changes

Comment: no it won't unless those dips go below the `0` line in which case you need to more clearly define what you mean by positive curves. once you have applied `> 0` to `data` all of those dips dissapear

Comment: I just saw your edit, you problem was calling `diff(tvecN)>0` instead of `diff(tvecN > 0)` - there is a vast difference between the two

Comment: @Dan Ahh! now i get it I see my problem now thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach was pretty close i.e.

```
startindex = (find(diff(x)>0)) + 1
endindex = (find(diff(x)<0))
```

Rather try

```
posData = [0, x>0] %prepend with zero to catch if the data starts with a positive region
startindex = find(diff(posData) == 1) 
endindex = find(diff(posData) == -1)
```